# Training loss not changing at all (PyTorch)

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, nlp, pytorch, lstm

I am trying to solve a text classification problem. My training data has input as a sequence of 80 numbers in which each represent a word and target value is just a number between 1 and 3.
I pass it through this model:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, tokenize_vocab_count):
        super().__init__()
        self.embd = nn.Embedding(tokenize_vocab_count+1, 300)
        self.embd_dropout = nn.Dropout(0.3)
        self.LSTM = nn.LSTM(input_size=300, hidden_size=100, dropout=0.3, batch_first=True)
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(100, 1024)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(1024, 512)
        self.lin_dropout = nn.Dropout(0.8)
        self.lin3 = nn.Linear(512, 3)

    def forward(self, inp):
        inp = self.embd_dropout(self.embd(inp))
        inp, (h_t, h_o) = self.LSTM(inp)
        h_t = F.relu(self.lin_dropout(self.lin1(h_t)))
        h_t = F.relu(self.lin_dropout(self.lin2(h_t)))
        out = F.softmax(self.lin3(h_t))
        return out
```

My training loop is as follows:

```
model = Model(tokenizer_obj.count+1).to('cuda')

optimizer = optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-2)
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

EPOCH = 10

for epoch in range(0, EPOCH):
     for feature, target in tqdm(author_dataloader):
         train_loss = loss_fn(model(feature.to('cuda')).view(-1,  3), target.to('cuda'))
         optimizer.zero_grad()
         train_loss.backward()
         optimizer.step()
      print(f"epoch: {epoch + 1}\tTrain Loss : {train_loss}")
```

I printed out the feature and target dimension and it is as follows:

```
torch.Size([64, 80]) torch.Size([64])
```

Here 64 is the batch_size.
I am not doing any validation as of now.
When I train I am getting a constant loss value and no change

```
/home/koushik/Software/miniconda3/envs/fastai/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py:50: UserWarning: dropout option adds dropout after all but last recurrent layer, so non-zero dropout expects num_layers greater than 1, but got dropout=0.3 and num_layers=1
  "num_layers={}".format(dropout, num_layers))
  0%|                                                                                                                                                 | 0/306 [00:00<?, ?it/s]/media/koushik/Backup Plus/Code/Machine Deep Learning/NLP/src/Deep Learning/model.py:20: UserWarning: Implicit dimension choice for softmax has been deprecated. Change the call to include dim=X as an argument.
  out = F.softmax(self.lin3(h_t))
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 306/306 [00:03<00:00, 89.36it/s]
epoch: 1        Train Loss : 1.0986120700836182
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 306/306 [00:03<00:00, 89.97it/s]
epoch: 2        Train Loss : 1.0986120700836182
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 306/306 [00:03<00:00, 89.35it/s]
epoch: 3        Train Loss : 1.0986120700836182
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 306/306 [00:03<00:00, 89.17it/s]
epoch: 4        Train Loss : 1.0986120700836182
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 306/306 [00:03<00:00, 88.72it/s]
epoch: 5        Train Loss : 1.0986120700836182
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 306/306 [00:03<00:00, 87.75it/s]
epoch: 6        Train Loss : 1.0986120700836182
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 306/306 [00:03<00:00, 85.67it/s]
epoch: 7        Train Loss : 1.0986120700836182
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 306/306 [00:03<00:00, 85.40it/s]
epoch: 8        Train Loss : 1.0986120700836182
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 306/306 [00:03<00:00, 84.49it/s]
epoch: 9        Train Loss : 1.0986120700836182
100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 306/306 [00:03<00:00, 84.21it/s]
epoch: 10       Train Loss : 1.0986120700836182
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) applies log-softmax, but you are also applying softmax to the model's output, that is harmful, you should remove it. Also setting the linear dropout to 0.8 is quite high, maybe try it with a lower dropout probability first or disable it entirely just to verify that the model works.

Comment: Also learning rate is pretty high, you may want to set it to something 10/30 times lower or so

Comment: Thanks @MichaelJungo The problem was the softmax in the output of model. I reduced the dropout and reduced the learning rate as well. Now the model seems to train but the loss is going up and down repeatedly. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MichaelJungo Add an answer to this question and I will mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss), which applies log-softmax, but you also apply softmax in the model:

```py
out = F.softmax(self.lin3(h_t))
```

The output of your model should be the raw logits, without the `F.softmax`.